# PayPal not sending correct item_number in IPN API call

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have a hosted PayPal form setup for a Subscribe button.

I send the return URL like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://myurl.com/returnurl" />
```

This works fine, upon payment the user gets redirected to this URL.

I also send the item_number parameter like so

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="{{uid}}" />
```

`{{uid}}` is a template tag and I have verified when viewing the source code it is being filled correctly. For testing I was using `uid` 15.

When the user clicks the PayPal Subscribe button it takes them to the PayPal gateway. I have verified by using Developer Tools in Chrome that the correct `uid` (15 in this case) is being sent in the HTTP headers.

The problem is that all IPN notifications have the `item_number` `1` (I'm checking in the IPN history of the PayPal website, where it lists the parameters sent for each message.)

Can anyone think of why `item_number` is being sent as `1`, and not the correct value?

Thanks

Comment: did you try the invoice, Pass-through variable you can use to identify your invoice number for this purchase.

Default – No variable is passed back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears item_number isn't always a variable you can set. When setting up a product to sell in the PayPal control panel you specify and item description and an item number. I'd setup the item_number of 1 and so even though I was setting it in my HTML `<form>` it was being overwritten by the item number I'd already setup.

The solution was to use a different custom field.